# Removing New Line Using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to remove Vertical Tab and Back Space (Character ASCII code 013 010) using python? I try below codes but not working.

```
text = re.sub('\n', ' ', text) // after execute, removed all text except for last line
text = text.replace('\n',' ') // after execute, removed all text except for last line
text = text.rstrip() 
text = text.lstrip()
text = text.strip()
```

this is a raw string:

```
Only certified persons are allowed to use the research equipment and facilities
 at NSL. There are several things users need to do before they are given access
 to the labs. All new users must complete steps 1-3 (and step 4 for those planning 
 to perform chemical operations at NSL.)


 Every user must complete the user form and submit it to nanosystemslaboratory@osu.edu. 
 Internal users (OSU users) must fill the erequest number under the chartfield section of the user form. 
 Failure to provide an erequest number for the associated chartfield may delay processing of the user form.
```

Desired Output is single line text for example: line1 line2 line3

```
Only certified persons ... Every user must complete the user ...
```

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: single line text

Comment: What does this have anything to do with vertical tab and backspace?

Comment: I wrote it, because I tried everything. Character code may be the cause of the error.

Comment: Update the question with an example of desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is '\r' and ascii code equivalent 013 too. Thanks for everyone. this below statements is useful for removing back space character.

```
text = text.replace('\r',' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to try is `line.strip()`. It works with both spaces and tabs and preserves the spaces in between.

```
line = '   this is my example          '
line.strip() == 'this is my example'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
text = text.replace('\n', '')
text = text.replace(' ', '')
```

If I understood your problem, this lines should be enough for a solution. For summary, I removed newlines first and spaces after than that.

Comment: Output is "Therequiredcoursesare:" so that's not working brother.